# How to save date in a console application c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, executable

When you make a C++ console application on VisualStudio for example, when you use your application and you quit it, I think the data is lost is that right? Is there a way to not lose the data and make an .exe from the console project to have a program that you can open, close, open and modify the data?

Comment: All runtime objects, variables and other elements you create and use while the program is running is generally speaking held in RAM which obviously gets released and gave back to the system once the program exits. To achieve persistent state you can use files and write data to them that you want to keep. Google ifstream, ofstream and fstream if you are using C++.

Comment: @AdrianLis But is there a way to make an application that saves the data?

Comment: @AdrianLis I am making a program where I will keep the data in text files, but do you know I way I can make an executable from my console application project so I don't have to go run the source code from the ide.

Comment: Explain what that means. You are not going to write your own compiler.

Comment: There is no difference between a console application and an application that runs in the windowing subsystem (or any other subsystem for that matter): When a process terminates, all information stored in transient memory is lost, as the OS reclaims that memory. If you need to persist information across runs you need to serialize it and persist it in some way. The file system is a common storage medium for persistent data, as is a database (either a custom DB engine, or the registry), or cloud-backed storage.

Comment: When the IDE runs the program it does create an exe.  So what you are asking is where does the exe get created when you run your program in the IDE?  It probably depends on the IDE but you could search the computer for a file with the name of your project and .exe you should be able to find it.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah, I assume you are unfamiliar with Visual Studio. Those of us familiar with VS can provide a better answer.

Comment: @user34660  I never intended to answer the question - that's why it was a comment.

Comment: This guy who's familiar with visual studio tells people to search their computers for files instead of telling them where the files are, all the time. Teach a man to fish and he can feed himself.

Comment: I very much believe in "teach a man to fish" and I think there is a better answer than either searching the computer for files or telling them where the files are. The best answer is to explain projects and how to look in the project. Since in this case the person is such a beginner I did not explain about projects any more than at an extremely beginner level.

Comment: @IInspectable "The file system is a common storage medium for persistent data, as is a database (either a custom DB engine, or the registry), or cloud-backed storage". You mean that inside my code I have to go save the information somewhere? For example, if I have an object of a class with a vector of strings for attribute, will the string of the vector be deleted when I exit the program?

Comment: This has been explained several times now: When a process terminates, its entire memory is gone. Unless you write information to persistent storage (like the local file system), everything is gone when the process terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use your application in Visual Studio it first creates an executable file, an exe file. The C++ file is compiled and linked. The compiling and linking is called a build.

At the bottom of Visual Studio you will see an "Output" window. Errors will appear there if there are any. If there are **not** errors then you will see a line similar to the following.

```
1>  SO36972615.vcxproj -> c:\users\sam\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SO36972615\Debug\SO36972615.exe
```

Here, "SO36972615" is the project name. The project is at:

```
c:\users\sam\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SO36972615
```

The project files are in that directory. There is a "Debug" subdirectory with an exe file in it, SO36972615.exe. You can execute that file outside of VS. You can also copy it to some other place in **your** system.

To use your program in another system, you will probably need to do what is called a Release build. You need to learn about that too. If you do a Release build then you might be able to just copy your exe file to another system.

You probably need a setup system to install your program into another system. A setup is also called a deployment and programmers often say they need to deploy their software. Learning how to deploy (create a setup for) your program will take time but that is how you would be able to use your program in other systems.

Comment: Ok thank you it is clear, but do you know if I have in my code an object of a class with a vector of strings for attribute, if the strings will be deleted at the exit of the program?

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Yes, .Net will delete objects during execution that are no longer needed. Windows will release storage used by an application when the application exits. So if you use classes such as String and StringBuilder then the storage used by them will be totally available to other applications when your application exits.